# Why does string not implement IList<char>?

Tags: c#, .net, string

*Title says all*

**Why does `String` implement `IEnumerable<char>` and not `IList<char>`?**

A string has a length and you can already take elements from a specific index.
And it could be indicated that it is immutable with `ICollection<char>.IsReadOnly`.

*So what could be wrong with it? Am I missing something?*

**As many answers point on that:**
There is not an interface for read only lists/collections alone, but as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` shows I think its definitely possible and with it's `IsReadOnly` Property designed for such cases.

```
   public class String : IList<char>
    {
        int IList<char>.IndexOf(char item)
        {
            // ...
        }

        void IList<char>.Insert(int index, char item)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        void IList<char>.RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        char IList<char>.this[int index]
        {
            set
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

        void ICollection<char>.Add(char item)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        void ICollection<char>.Clear()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public bool Contains(char item)
        {
            // ...
        }

        public void CopyTo(char[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            // ...
        }

        int ICollection<char>.Count
        {
            get { return this.Length; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        bool ICollection<char>.Remove(char item)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: As you note, it's immutable, so why would implementing an interface that is primarily concerned with making changes make any sense?

Comment: @Hightechrider - Why does ICollection has a `IsReadOnly` Property if it may not be used? I think its defently worth and mainly .. everything is there. Indexing and Length. _(And give those changing method explicit implementations throwing a `NotSupportedException`)_

Comment: @Hightechrider - And why does arrays implement `IList` then?

Comment: Because arrays are not immutable.

Comment: @Hans Passant - But they still have to implement `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear` _(Which are the main mutating methods)_ and can not be used on them. _(Another reason you need IsFixedSize in the generic version of ICollection!)_

Comment: @ordag - the indexer is the big banana.  ICollection doesn't specify one.  Think back to .NET 1.x

Comment: @Hans Passant - I not only want `ICollection<char>` on string, but `IList<char>`. _(Was referring to `ICollection`'s `IsFixedSize` which should be present in `ICollection<T>` and therefore `IList<T>`, too.)_

Comment: _It's even `IList`'s `IsFixedSize` ... but thats not important._ Array and `ReadOnlyList<T>` show that implementing `IList<T>` without working `Add`, ... is possible.

Comment: SO users wanting to implement their own framework is pretty common.  Having anybody actually want to use it is not.  A framework that implements IList for a string type is a major code smell.  Good luck with it.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Followed this question a while and read all its comments? This code up there should be the one, builtin string class if it would implement the interfaces for the features it already provides ...

Comment: If you want IList functionality, why not just use String.ToCharArray() rather than rolling your own?

Comment: @Jason Yes, but I mainly think about IList<char> on string because everythings there already ... but thats the alternative.

Comment: @ordag: you seem to ask the honest question "why is string not IList<char>"; yet, when people give the _wrong_ answer, you tell them (a) the framework is wrong (b) the people answering are wrong. Oh, and when someone points it out (Hans Passant, not just anyone) you play ad hominem and question whether he actually read this discussion. (At several others, you assume people don't understand your intentions with the IsReadOnly property. Same deal). Why ask? Right now, this has just degenerated to that: a subjective, argumentative discussion.

Comment: @sehe - Uhm .. what should be inappropriate in asking if he read it, if he blames me wanting my own "crap" framework when I'm asking about BCL?
I repeated some question many times _(and yes I have to admit I was .. unhappy .. after a while)_, searched for a discussion, asked about their opinions: But many times I felt ignored. Please count all statements which are not: "Immutable `IList/Collection` implementations are just bad".
And then look if someone replied to any of my counter arguments. _(I mean .. really .. that array thing was just ignored after saying I'm wrong)_

Comment: @sehe - Do not say I wouldn't accep others view _(and that is what this question is about, isn't it, what should a "solution" look like?)_. _(Look at conversation with chibacity, of course I understand him, even if I may not have the same opinion 100%!)_
Oh and PLEASE, if you say I would just blame others that they don't understand me, SHOW me WHERE I'm wrong, tell me where someone acutally responded to my argument with `IsReadOnly`.

Comment: @sehe - tl;dr: If someone tries to exmplain me, why something is bad design, I also want an answer if I can show some counter examples. _(I mean this is all voluntarily .. but if you'd like to have upvotes, I'd expect that here in this question)_

Comment: @ordag, not making `string` implement `IList<char>` was a *decision*.  We thought you were asking for reasons that someone would have made the choice Microsoft did; no one is going to be able to tell why it would have been impossible, because that isn't true.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - Of course I'm asking why Mircosoft did it, and of course this question can't change anything. But say me why I should simply accept the answer "Bad design because it's mutable" when I can show you where Microsoft did **exactly** the same at other places, all over the framework. Maybe there's something else? _(And again, I upvoted two questions yet, but someone definitely need to give a reasonable statement if I show anything against an answer)_

Comment: @ordag Jeff Sternal gave you the best possible answer, don't attack him. He did not say that it would be bad design to implement `IList<char>`, nor did he say that if it was bad, it would be because of mutability. You ask an interesting question, but we can't answer it. If anyone can, it's the BCL team. And even they might say: "no reason, we just decided to spend our time on something we thought was more important". UPDATE: I just notice he does say it's about mutability in his answer.

Answer (score 14):

Mainly because `IList` inherits from `ICollection`, and strings do not support the mutable beahviors `ICollection` promises (add, remove, & clear) - when you add or remove character elements from a string, it creates a new string.

---

Implementing *part* of an interface is bad design. You might do it sometimes out of necessity, but it's never a good choice. It's better to split the interface. (The .NET collection interfaces should probably have been split to segregate the mutable members from the diagnostic ones.) Meta-functions like `IsReadOnly` make the interface less coherent and make it harder to use.

So even though a string is in many respects a **list** - you can index a string and find the count of characters in it - it's pretty rare that someone's actually going to want to treat a string like an `IList<char>`, especially in a post-3.5-world when there are simple transformations available that make it easy to get this information from an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Yeah, thats true, but a string is a read only list/collection. And I think those interfaces doesn't prohibit those implementations

Comment: So same for `ReadOnlyCollection`? _(And Sorry if I repeat myself)_ And `ICollection` has a property for showing if those methods for mutation can be used.

Comment: @ordag - I think `ReadOnlyCollection` was basically a bad idea (perhaps a necessary evil given the state of the 2.0 base class library). Making immutable types implement interfaces that imply mutability makes it harder for callers to do anything reasonable with them.

Comment: @ordag, IEnumerable<T> doesn't allow modification of the collection. IList<T> does allow modification of the collection. With a list being an immutable object having it use IList<T> makes no sense what so ever.

Comment: @Jeff So does a Stream which may not be written to? (See `CanWrite`). If you have a method accepting ICollection, and you want to add something, i thing its perfect to first ask `IsReadOnly`? And otherwise throw an `ArgumentException`. Its very easy to determine if it is readonly and is REQUIRED to be done with the fact thas there is this property.

Comment: @Jeff I see your point, and it can definitely be a trap, but I still think the added value is worth it

Comment: @odag: when I code against `IList`, I don't have to check `IsReadOnly` before calling one of the mutable members, except in very unusual circumstances. In what case does would it add enough value to justify the additional confusion? You can call `"Hello, World".ToList()` and get a true list of characters.

Comment: @Jeff - _(i think of generic interface versions here)_ And there you have to if your method is exposed externally, if I give you a `ReadOnlyCollection` for example. And I think the confusion would be minimal for explicit implementations. So a `"Hello".Add('a');` would not even compile! (_I'm currently using strings ToCharArray() :)_)

Comment: Let's turn this around. In what case should you ever ask for an `IList<T>` as opposed to an `IEnumerable<T>`? In other words, when should you force the caller to provide you with a list instead of something less restrictive? I think the only answer is "when you need to modify the input."

Comment: I can give you an example why `ICollection<T>`. If I want to enumerate over it and get to know how many elements it will be. _(`ICollection<T>` has the problematic methods, so `IList<T>` would just be a bonus for the already available indexer)_

Answer (score 5):

The fact that `ReadOnlyCollection` supports `IList` is in my opinion highly: **meh**.

`IList` is a contract that indicates that implementers support collection mutation (e.g. Add, Remove, Insert) which on an immutable object is clearly wrong. Carrying this over to `System.String` is just plain wrong as it is also immutable by design.

`System.String` implementing `IList` would be a terrible API design as a bunch of the methods would not work, so strings would not work in the same way as types that fully implement `IList`.

Perhaps you are hopping that it supported a more liberal interface, sure, but `IList` is not the right choice.

Partial interface implementation like this breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and introduces potential runtime bugs.

**Update**

Interestingly enough, .Net 4.5 introduces the new [IReadOnlyList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. However, `String` does not implement it, and it could not be introduced into the `IList` hierarchy.

Some background: http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/ReadOnly-WInRT.

Comment: Why should it be a wrong dresign? `IList<char>` is an `ICollection<char>`. And `ICollection<char>` **IS** designed to may be read only (See `IsReadOnly`). And it adds way more value then `IEnumerable<char>` provides. (`Count`, Its there .. named `Length`!). Such a string can clearly be used with any `ICollection<char>` implementation since you already **HAVE TO** check for mutability!
_And I'm for explicit implementation of `Add`, ... for solving the only problem: Understanding for unaware, new users!_
Oh and `IList<char>` is then just a bonus (Direct access over index, it's there, too).

Comment: @ordag It would be the wrong design as it breaks LSP. What you would actually like is for string to implement a more convenient interface, which I agree on, however, this interface does not exist.

Comment: @ordag I consider the `IsReadonly` property to be a bad design in the first place. It would have been better to split the interface into mutable and immutable aspects - this would then properly follow two good design principles: Interface Segregation and LSP. It breaks both!

Comment: I don't see that, an `ICollection<char>` string would implement `Add`, ... but with `NotSupportedException`s. And we don't need a new interface, why should `ICollection` not be used in read only implementations? Think of the `Add` `IsReadOnly` relation as equal to `Write` and `CanWrite` at `Stream` _(Thats an abstract class but I think you can project here)_. Is a readonly stream bad design, too? _(So you first check, `Can*` I do that or `Is*` that logical group of methods not available)_

Comment: @ordag I understand your concept, I just think it would make for a poor API.

Comment: And you can move your argumentation to arrays, too _(nearly, replace, but not add)_ Are arrays implementing `IList` also bad design?
Yeah it's really controversial and will probably never be implemented. But I think from a logical point of view it should be that way.

Comment: Yes, I could move my argument to Arrays - correct. The framework isn't perfect. This is why I am hinting that we're hoping for interfaces that do not exist.

Comment: True .. sometimes I wish there would be no backward compatibility and some things could be designed from scratch ...

Answer (score 2):

Why should it? I think there isn't many cases where that would be useful. Most of the time, when you have string, you know it's a string. And when you don't, `IEnumerable<char>` is often good enough.

What's more `IList<T>` (and `ICollection<T>`) are interfaces for *mutable* collections, which `string` isn't. (Although `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does implement them.)

Comment: Ok, ultimate counter question ;D
Why does an array implement `IList`?!

Comment: Well an array is mutable, unlike a string.

Comment: @Inuyasha - Yeah, but fixed size .. so no `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear`

Comment: Because it's useful. It makes sense to have a return type of `IList<Foo>` and then return an array. It doesn't make much sense to have a return type of `IList<char>` and then return `string`. You should have a return type of `string` in the first place, you're not going to use another type instead in the future.

Comment: @svick - Basically the situation when I thought about this was, when I designed a class which takes a collection of chars to generate something. A collection based type seemd good to me for that. But just passing a string felt right true, because .. it IS a collection from a logical point.

Comment: @svick - I just see added value with a IList string, it feels right, and prohibiting mutable methods is easy, too.

Comment: Wouldn't `IEnumerable<char>` be enough in that case? And I think `string` has a slightly different meaning than a collection of characters. It's meaning is that it represents some text. When you really want a collection of characters, the parameter should be `IList<char>` (or `IEnumerable<char>`), not `string`.

Comment: @svick - But everything _(besides those mutable methods)_ is still there, just not ... associated ... with the interface _(index, length)_. So just looking what you can do with a string today: You can take one char after the other from it, it's a determinable count of chars, and you can take one from specific indexes. This seems like a list to me!

Comment: @svick - Yeah I have an `ICollection<char>` as a parameter, and I want to pass a string which is even an _"ordered"_, fixed size, list of chars.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, that it isn't a IList (you can't `"hello world".Add('!')` -- this is an interface and contract incompatibility; it is not just a read only list, because that would 'know' that `Add` operation, and throw on invocation).

---

Also strings have special semantics - storage optimization and identity aliasing come to mind (there can be small string optimizations, there can be interned strings). These wouldn't stand out once you pass as `IList<char>` - people might start to expect 'normal' List<>-like semantics.

When seeing `IEnumerable<char>`, however, no such expectations are raised (it is just saying: I am able to give you a number of characters in succession, you don't need to know where they come from).

Comment: I'd say a string is a list for sure, a list of chars. Maybe not technically, but logically. And explicitly implementing that not supported methods (like ReadOnlyCollection does) to keep a away unaware users seems good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the alternative below has not been brought up yet...

**System.String does support this** (albeit indirectly).  Yes it makes another copy in memory, but I believe that is designed that way because strings are immutable.

```
string myString = "hello world";    
IList<char> myIList = myString.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Good one, thats what I may use instead

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `String` does not implement `IList<char>` doesn't surprise me. In fact, what does surprise me somewhat, is that it implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Why? Because a string is not really a sequence of chars.

You see, there are 1,114,112 code points in Unicode, but a `char` is only 16 bits. The string contains a sequence of characters (i.e. unicode code points), that is encoded using UTF16 in a number of `char` values. As a result, the number of unicode characters in a string may be less than the number of `char` values in the string.

Now, I do realize that this sounds very weird to most people, especially those that speak English, because they have always been happy with ASCII, and assumed that one `char` equals one character. In many cases, that assumption is even true. That may be the reason why `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, as some sort of compromise with a legacy, non-unicode world.

But the truth is that we cannot possible answer your question. The only ones that can tell you why they designed strings the way they did, are the people on the BCL team at the time.